# Python PyQt QFileSystemModel Root Path

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qfilesystemmodel

This is the code i have to display a tree view of a directory called "C:\Myfolder".

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

class Myview(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        model = QtGui.QFileSystemModel()
        model.setRootPath('C:\Myfolder')
        view = QtGui.QTreeView()
        view.setModel(model)
        self.setCentralWidget(view)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myview = Myview()
    myview.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Even though i set the `RootPath` to "C:\Myfolder" , the tree view display all the drives and folder.

How can i limit the `QFileSystemModel` so that `TreeView` only display items inside "C:\Myfolder" directory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would need to add `view.setRootIndex(model.index("C:\Myfolder"))` according to the [QFileSystemModel documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfilesystemmodel.html#example-usage).

Comment: Another explanation with the same solution is provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57193760/2961550

Answer (score -1):

It is extremely important that you write `"C:/Myfolder"` and NOT `"C:\Myfolder"`. Otherwise, it thinks the directory does not exist and will always show you all drives and all folders.