# How to limit QTreeView directory in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have this directory structure:

```
files
  |----showme
  |       |------asd.h
  |       |------homework.docx
  |       |------free games.exe
  |----my internet history
  |         |-----------dont show me
```

I would like it so that the QTreeView will only show the files/showme directory.
How can I do this?

this is my code:

```
self.model.setRootPath('H:\\files\\showme')  
self.tree = QTreeView(self)  
self.tree.resize(620,300)  
self.tree.move(0,200)  
self.tree.setModel(self.model)
```

EDIT: to clarify, I want it so that the base directory will be showme

EDIT2: wrong code here, whoops!

Comment: have you tried `self.model.setRootPath('H:\\PROJECT\\'+ str(ProjNum)+'\\files\\showme')`???

Comment: that doesn't seem to do anything, it still opens the TreeView at "My Computer"

Comment: [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19948159/python-pyqt-qfilesystemmodel-root-path)

Comment: Thank you that worked for me